# Unable to run durable functions locally in visual studio 2019

Tags: azure-functions

I am getting the below error when I try to run out of box durable function code.This seems to be happening suddenly from today.I was able to run durable functions locally before on the same machine.

One more observation is the extensions.json file is not getting generated for me in the bin/debug folder.If I add the nuget package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator the extensios.json is getting generated but this package seems to require .net core 2.1 dependency.

```
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       3.0.3904 Commit hash: c345f7140a8f968c5dbc621f8a8374d8e3234206  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 3.3.1.0

[2021-11-25T08:48:47.546Z] Found C:\Users\g\source\repos\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2021-11-25T08:48:48.944Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1_HttpStart'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'starter' to type IDurableOrchestrationClient. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
[2021-11-25T08:48:48.977Z] Error indexing method 'Function1_HttpStart'
[2021-11-25T08:48:48.978Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1_HttpStart'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'starter' to type IDurableOrchestrationClient. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
[2021-11-25T08:48:48.980Z] Function 'Function1_HttpStart' failed indexing and will be disabled.
[2021-11-25T08:48:48.983Z] No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
[2021-11-25T08:48:49.008Z] The 'Function1' function is in error: The binding type(s) 'orchestrationTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.
[2021-11-25T08:48:49.011Z] The 'Function1_Hello' function is in error: The binding type(s) 'activityTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.
[2021-11-25T08:48:49.012Z] The 'Function1_HttpStart' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1_HttpStart'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'starter' to type IDurableOrchestrationClient. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

Functions:

        Function1_HttpStart: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/Function1_HttpStart

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2021-11-25T08:48:55.961Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000E73BFCBE'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the ***Azure Durable Function*** from the ***Visual Studio 2019*** and the execution is successful by following the below steps:

1. Visual Studio 2019 > Created New Azure Functions Project (Http Trigger) > Added New Item called as Durable Functions Orchestration and named as Function1 by default.

**Code:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace KrishHttpTriggerFuncApp
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var outputs = new List<string>();
        // Replace "hello" with the name of your Durable Activity Function.
        outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", "Tokyo"));
        outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", "Seattle"));
        outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", "London"));

        // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
        return outputs;
    }

    [FunctionName("Function1_Hello")]
    public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Saying hello to {name}.");
        return $"Hello {name}!";
    }

    [FunctionName("Function1_HttpStart")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
        ILogger log)
    {
        // Function input comes from the request content.
        string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Function1", null);

        log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

        return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
    }
   }
}
```

**host.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**.csproj code:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="2.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.13" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

These are the project dependencies, packages installed for this ***Azure Functions [Http Trigger] - Durable Functions Orchestration***:

[image]

2. Build the project (Ctrl + shift + B) and Executed the function locally (F5).

**Output:**
[image]

Copied the URL and run in browser:

[image]

3. The response is the initial result from the HTTP function letting us know the durable orchestration has started successfully. It is not yet the end result of the orchestration. The response includes a few useful URLs. For now, let's query the status of the orchestration.
4. Copy the URL value for  `statusQueryGetUri`  and pasting it in the browser's address bar and execute the request.

[image]

This output shows us the instance has completed, and includes the outputs or results of the durable function.

Comment: Do you have .net core 2.1 on your machine. For me too if I have .net core 2.1 It is working. Not sure whey a function created with version 3 requires .net core 2.1.This package Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator is searching for .net core 2.1

Comment: Hello @GeethaB, Could you please share your .csproj code of the version 3 function!